# Must contain a query definition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo, aws-appsync

Iam new to react-native and appsync,graphql.we are trying to implement an appsync app using react-native when i tried to run its is throwing an error saying

> 14:16:38: Must contain a query definition.
>   * null:null in getQueryDefinition
>   - node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:649:64 in diffQueryAgainstStore
>   - node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:559:32 in readQueryFromStore
>   - node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:899:38 in read
>   - node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:992:23 in readQuery
>   * null:null in update
>   - node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1609:0 in 
>   - node_modules/apollo-utilities/lib/bundle.umd.js:818:21 in tryFunctionOrLogError
>   * null:null in 
>   - node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/bundle.umd.js:961:22 in performTransaction
>   - node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1473:0 in markMutationResult
>   - node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:797:20 in next
>   - node_modules/zen-observable-ts/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:150:3 in notifySubscription
>   - node_modules/zen-observable-ts/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:195:5 in onNotify
>   * null:null in next
>   - node_modules/zen-observable-ts/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:150:3 in notifySubscription
>   * null:null in flushSubscription
>   - node_modules/zen-observable-ts/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:190:26 in 
>   * null:null in 
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in 
>   - ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals

I tried to trace out the error in apollo-cache but i couldnt find one.Am getting this when ever i press send button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class ChatInput extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.userid = props.userid;
      this.state = {
          text: ''
      }
  }

  handleSend = () => {
      if (this.state.text === '') {
          return false;
      }
      const chat = {
          userid: this.userid,
          text: this.state.text,
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
      }
      this.props.onSubmit(chat);
      this.setState({
         text: ''
      })
      this.textInput.clear();
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <TextInput ref={input => { this.textInput = input }} placeholder="Message.." 
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} onSubmitEditing={this.handleSend} 
        autoFocus={true} blurOnSubmit={false} returnKeyType="send"></TextInput>
        <Button title="Send" onPress={this.handleSend}></Button>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}



 const ChatInputData = compose(
    graphql(PostMessage, {
        options: {
            fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
        },props: (props) => ({
                onSubmit: chat => {
                    props.mutate({
                        variables: chat,
                        optimisticResponse: {
                            __typename: 'Mutation',
                            post: {
                                __typename: ChatHistory,
                                id: chat.createdAt,
                               userid: chat.userid,
                                text: chat.text,
                                createdAt: chat.createdAt
                            }
                        },
                        update: (proxy, {data: {post}}) => {
                            const data = proxy.readQuery({ query: PostMessage });
                            data.listPostMessages.items.push(Object.assign({}, post));
                            proxy.writeData({query: listPostMessages, data});
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    )(ChatInput)
```

Please help me out!.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us a part of your reducer ? I think the error can occured in your "onSubmit" action. Because in your component you do not reference apollo cache

Comment: Just Updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this error by correcting my mutation ie PostMesssage in my case.This error

> Must contain a query definition

mainly occur if your query is incorrect which you have written in graphql. Start seeing how you passing your variables and how you use them and how you define them.

Answer (score 0):

At this line :

```
 const data = proxy.readQuery({ query: PostMessage });
```

I do not see a reference to `PostMessage` where you want to define your query.

Comment: please check that i already had the reference but still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error means that in the imported `PostMessage`, the query could not be found. Make sure it looks like this: (and not the shorthand equivalent)

```
query postMessage($id: ID!) {
    postMessage(id: $id) {
        id
        title
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Karens helped me in correcting my mutation defination

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I had added new resolver functions (in new files) but failed to include references to these resolvers into graphql's executable schema.